# Add events in for loop

Tags: javascript, events

I'd like to change the innerText of each `<p>` to `*` with a mouseover event.

**HTML**

```
<p id="object1">O</p>
<p id="object2">O</p>
<p id="object3">O</p>
```

I wrote a script, but it affects only the last `<p>`. What is wrong in my script? I would be grateful for a help.

**JavaScript**

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var obj = Utility.$(nodeList[i].id);
    obj.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        obj.innerHTML = '*';
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Simplest solution is `let obj = ...`.

Comment: even simpler is `this.innerHTML = '*';`

Comment: It's a little bit too much to explain closures here. Of course it would help to understand the issue, but for this case it's enough to explain that the event handler brings the affected element via `event.target` as argument IMO.

Comment: or even better, that the context `this` within the handler is a different one than the context of the loop. The context within a event handler is exactly `event.target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the event argument in the event handler, otherwise `obj` is the last assignent (assigned in the loop).

And you don't need any `Utility` helper

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
{ 
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        e.target.innerHTML = '*';
    }, false);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/002efeht/